# Output is Rendered differently when using( forloop vs setInterval,requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm facing problem with ForLoop vs (setInterval,requestAnimationFrame)
The Code below simply draws random rectangle on canvas.
I'm avoiding to make this question large by Copy/pasting the whole code here, instead i'll post relevant code  with a Demo  
The issue is when i use 
1. For loop to draw 50 Rectangle i get All 50 Rectangle on screen as shown below, but instead of forloop 
2.if i use setInterval or requestAnimation(callback) i get Single rectangle.
 In second case Whenever a new Rectangle is drawn previously drawn rectangle is Clear so final o/p i get as single Rectangle but this is not happening if i use a forloop Why so?
I have tested my case with

> ForLoop,setInterval and requestAnimationFrame

**using For loop:**
My Code Flow goes this way and a [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyzzNQ?editors=0010):

```
function main() {
 .....
  drawRects();
}
function drawRects() {
for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
  setRectangle(gl, randomInt(100), randomInt(100),randomInt(100), randomInt(100));
  //draw Rectangle
  ....
}}
main();
```

and i get Output as:
[image: Output using a For loop]

**using requestAnimationFrame/ similary with  setInterval:**
My Code Flow goes this way and a [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpEZqQ?editors=1010):

```
function main() {
 .....
  render();
}
function render(){
    if(rectCount < 50){
        drawRects();
        rectCount++;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
function drawRects() {
  setRectangle(gl, randomInt(100), randomInt(100),randomInt(100), randomInt(100));
  //draw Rectangle
  ....
}
main();
```

[image: Output using requestANimation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because WebGL clears the canvas after it composites

If you don't want WebGL to clear the canvas after compositing you can pass in `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when creating the context

```
var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
```

at the possible expense of some perf.

Some other Q&As that have more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331594/128511

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790802/128511

Comment: Thanks for Answering I'm following your tutorial and thnks for tutorial

Comment: thanks, I should clearly add something about this to the tutorials